# Drawing Multiple Models in OpenGL 3.x/4.x

Tags: opengl

I'm working on a rendering engine and so far it's been coming great, but I can not figure out why when I make two drawing calls to render different models, only 1 will show up.

I'm using wxWidgets to handle the window system, the code in question is pasted below.  Any suggestions?

### Main Rendering Loop

```
TestShader.Activate();
glUseProgram(TestShader.Program);

ProjectionMatrix = glm::perspective(45.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
int projectionMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(TestShader.Program, "ProjectionMatrix");
glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(ProjectionMatrix));

glm::mat4 ViewMatrix = glm::lookAt(
                            glm::vec3(position),          
                            glm::vec3(position+direction),
                            glm::vec3(up)                 
                       );
int viewMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(TestShader.Program, "ViewMatrix");
glUniformMatrix4fv(viewMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(ViewMatrix));

TestModel[1].Draw(TestShader, glm::vec3(0,0,-11));
TestModel[0].Draw(TestShader, glm::vec3(0,0,-1));

Refresh(false);
```

### Model Drawing Function

```
void E_MODEL::Draw(EShader Shader, glm::vec3 Location)
{
if (!Registered) glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO[0]);
glBindVertexArray(VAO[0]);

if (!Registered) glGenBuffers(1, &VBO[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[0]);
if (!Registered) glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &Vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

if (!Registered) glGenBuffers(1, &VBO[1]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[1]);
if (!Registered) glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Normals.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &Normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[0]);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[1]);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);


glm::mat4 modelMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), Location);

int modelMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(Shader.Program, "modelMatrix");
glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelMatrix));
glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, Vertices.size() );


glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindVertexArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

Registered = true;
}
```

### Vertex Shader

```
#version 330 core

// Input vertex data, different for all executions of this shader.
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertexColor;

// Output data ; will be interpolated for each fragment.
out vec3 fragmentColor;
// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.
uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 ViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;

void main(){    

gl_Position =  ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1);

// The color of each vertex will be interpolated
// to produce the color of each fragment
fragmentColor = vertexColor;
}
```

### Fragment Shader

```
#version 330 core

// Interpolated values from the vertex shaders
in vec3 fragmentColor;

// Ouput data
out vec3 color;

void main(){

// Output color = color specified in the vertex shader, 
// interpolated between all 3 surrounding vertices
color = fragmentColor;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

`glClear` clears a buffer. With the `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` flag, you are clearing the color buffer. With the `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT` flag, you are clearing the depth buffer. By doing this each time you draw a model, the color and depth information written previously is cleared. This means you are erasing the image every time you draw a model.

You typically clear the buffers once per "paint" or "present". That is, you clear once, you draw N times, you present once. What you are doing now is clear, draw, clear, draw... present.

TL;DR: Call `glClear` once, before *all* of your drawing, not before each draw.

Comment: Wow. I completely overlooked that! And to think I spent 2 whole weeks figuring this thing out. Thank's guys!

Answer (score 1):

is it the `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` inside the draw function?  maybe move that out to before you make the calls the draw functions?